# Best practice to apply a modifier style to a block or an element

Tags: css, bem

I have a question of what is the best way to apply a style to a block or an element with the ABEM approach to CSS formatting and class naming.

I'm working on a site with WordPress and I have opted to use SCSS and use the ABEM (atomic) approach to BEM (Block, element and modifier) formatting and class naming technique. I know that I shouldn't add a modifier directly to an element so not like this: `<div class="-padding">To achieve some padding </div>`. Instead do this `<div class="a-col -padding">Better way to achieve some padding</div>`. Here is my problem:

Should I add the `-padding` to the `a-col` (like above) to achieve the padding, or should the `a-col` block have the padding applied to it directly in its CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, there is no reason to use the modifier in your case, so it's a go for declaring the padding directly on `a-col`.

The block in BEM are here to make a part of your CSS reusable, regardless of the usage context.
But, sometimes, you will have to handle particular cases. For example, in a specific case a block should be darker or smaller. That why we have the modifiers.

In your case:

- You just want to reuse a padding?
  => You should create a block
- It's a column and you already have a block for it, but this one should have a padding?
  =>  You should create a modifier

Comment: Ah okay, great thanks. Yeah all this BEM and ABEM gets a bit messy sometimes. But yeah now the modifier makes more sense to me thanks!

Comment: hi again, now when I have begun to use blocks instead of always using modifiers I know have the issue of me having too many blocks for an element... Now for a simple ```<h3 class="a-textCenter a-textWhite a-weight400">``` and this can't seem to be right?

Comment: Oh no! Most of the time, you should have only one block par element. You have to ask yourself what I am styling? In this case an in-text title? So perhaps `.a-title-in-text`? Now you will apply all the properties to this block. One block is not a part of your "css", it is a part of your "design".

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your input really does help! I now have another dilemma. Let's say that I want an ```h1``` to use another font like open-sans. The ```h1``` belongs to a container that has other styles applied to it so I could just select it via the CSS and change the font-family there. But I use a ```a-openSans``` block on other elements on my styles. So do I add the block class directly to the ```h1``` in the HTML,  or do I select it via the CSS of the container and style it there?

Comment: Block in the BEM methodology works at its best when your design is logical. It's perfect with Application, because it enforces consistency. In your case, I don't understand why a title is in Open Sans, and not the other ones. The reason of why you need this change, will determine how to do it in BEM. Your mind seems to be a good fit for the "Utility classes" methodology. I can advise you to read this two articles : https://davidtheclark.com/on-utility-classes/ and https://adamwathan.me/css-utility-classes-and-separation-of-concerns/

Comment: Thanks! The reason is that the designer of the project uses a font for almost all headings but on some headings, they want to use an open-sans so I created a a-openSans block to change that. Yeah thx will read!

Comment: To continue this conversation, ideally, there should not be a `a-title -openSans` in BEM. If you want to modifiy the CSS, a utility class is better because it will be available for all blocks : `a-title u-openSans`. For BEM a modifier should be logical, you need to ask the designer why this particular text is in Open Sans. For example, because it's between two paragraphs, so we could name our modifier `a-title -in-text`. It creates an abstraction layer to describe our intentions. It will be easier to understand and reuse the modifiers when we need to, it will help design consistency.

Comment: Ah, I see, so I now realise that I have to think about what type of purpose the modifier or block has to have, and then name and style it properly. Really great stuff thanks! And the links about the utility and component classes.

Comment: I'm happy to share this, and to see you understand what I try to explain :D